# Apply borders in a used cell Range VBA

Tags: vba, loops, excel, border

I am trying to apply **a border around a group of used cells dynamically**. The **column Range is (B7:E7)** The number of **rows** will always **vary**, so the code needs to be dynamic. My code below is not achieving this:

```
Sub Borders()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim lngLstCol As Long, lngLstRow As Long

lngLstRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
lngLstCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

For Each rngCell In Range("B7:B" & lngLstRow)
    If rngCell.Value > "" Then
        r = rngCell.row
        c = rngCell.Column
        Range(Cells(r, c), Cells(r, lngLstCol)).Select
            With Selection.Borders
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlThin
                .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            End With
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code applies border to every row where `B` column is `>""`. What do you exactly expect?

Comment: I wanted to be able to apply a boarder around used cells  from columns B7:C7 to lastrow so my code is error,

Comment: Can you add an image of sample expected output?

Comment: This code make borders around all cells  `B7` and beyond to right and down as expected..

Comment: @user3964075 for example i would like to apply a board around a range such as   Range("B6:E12"). The column range does not change it's B6:E6, just the row count varies depending on the data produced.  So its basically a Thick Box Border.

Comment: Which one do you want? 1) To put a border around all non-empty cells in a range 2) To put a border around a used range. If you have intended second why do you check if the cells are empty?

Comment: @kitapmitap  I actually intended for the second one. But the one you created works perfectly as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code puts borders around all non-empty cells beyond `B7`.

```
Sub Borders()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim lngLstCol As Long, lngLstRow As Long

    lngLstRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    lngLstCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    For Each rngCell In Range(Range("B7"), Cells(lngLstRow, lngLstCol))
        If rngCell.Value > "" Then
            rngCell.Select 'Select cells
            With Selection.Borders
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlThin
                .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            End With
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The code below puts borders around the used range beyond `B7`:

```
Sub BordersB()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim lngLstCol As Long, lngLstRow As Long

    lngLstRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    lngLstCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    With Range(Range("B7"), Cells(lngLstRow, 2)).Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With

    With Range(Range("B7"), Cells(7, lngLstCol)).Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With

    With Range(Cells(7, lngLstCol), Cells(lngLstRow, lngLstCol)).Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With

    With Range(Cells(lngLstRow, 2), Cells(lngLstRow, lngLstCol)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: @James I edited my code. You may also use this. This is better, may be faster.

Comment: How can this be the correct answer? You asked for borders in Columns(B:C), the code above will put borders on all cells below row 6 and ever column but column A

Comment: @Davesexcel this has been discussed above . apologies for the confusion. Thanks alot.

Comment: @James ı added a code which puts around the used range. (Of course it has nothing to do about empty cells.)

Comment: You should avoid `.Select`, so instead of using Select, just use : `With rngCell.Borders` or create a new non contiguous Range and then make the action to add the borders.

Comment: @danieltakeshi You are right; thanks: it is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

This will add borders to all none blank cells below row 6 in Columns(B:C)

```
    Sub AddBorders()
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range, c As Range

    Rws = Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(7, "B"), Cells(Rws, "C"))

    For Each c In Rng.Cells

        If c <> "" Then

            With c.Borders

                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlThin
                .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic

            End With

        End If

    Next c

End Sub
```